# Psycopg2: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database with psycopg2:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='puppetdb' user='puppetdb' host='172.17.0.1' port='5432' password='puppetdb'")
except Exception, e:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    print e
```

Which returns:

```
I am unable to connect to the database
'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

I've made sure that psycopg2 is installed with `pip install psycopg2` and it seems like this should work according to the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html).

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: In my case the user did not have read privileges to `/usr/local/lib`, where `psycopg2` was installed. Running with `sudo` or remedying the permissions on `/usr/local/lib` solved the problem.

Comment: This is really weird.

Comment: @dsclose that solved the problem for me too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This could be a name shadowing issue.

If your file is called psycopg2.py or if you have a psycopg2.py/psycopg2.pyc file in that directory then it will import your script over the actual pyscopg2 module.

If that's the issue then rename your file to something else.

Comment: Note that in my case I had a json.py file locally, which psycopg2 seems to reference internally, so it was leading to this too.

Answer (score 12):

For me it was because I was uploading a zip to AWS lambda and wasn't zipping the folder recursively, i.e. `zip lambda.zip *` instead of `zip -r lambda.zip *`. So the module folder was empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
import psycopg2               # Acc�s PostgreSQL
import psycopg2.extras        # Goodies PostgreSQL

try:
     conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='puppetdb' user='puppetdb' 
host='172.17.0.1' port='5432' password='puppetdb'")

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")
    print(e)
```