# Psycopg2: module object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect to a postgres database with psycopg2:

```
def get_posts():
 db = psycopg2.connect(database=DBNAME)
 c = db.cursor()
```

Which returns:

```
  File "/vagrant/forum/solution/forumdb_solved.py", line 9, in get_posts
  db = psycopg2.connect(database=DBNAME)
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

I have researched other solutions to this problem ([Psycopg2: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43767658/4623846)). None of my folder/file structure contains psycopg2 though. The other issue which seems to come up is read/write privileges of the folder in which psycopg2 is installed. I have psycopg2 installed in multiple locations (don't ask!) and not sure how to check this. Any help would be appreciated by a total newbie.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Hi @ZiyadEdher I'm using Python 2.7. I'm running it on a virtual machine on my laptop(windows).

Comment: Did you _ever_ have anything called `psycopg2` in any of your files?

Comment: Whether it is a Python file `psycopg2.py` or otherwise? (Obviously other than `import psycopg2`).

Comment: Please edit to your question the output from `print psycopg2`.

Comment: Not that I know about. I have checked all my immediate files and folders.

Comment: @IljaEverilä How do I go about doing this? Can I do it in the command line print(psycpog2)? What information are you looking for? Apologies for the stupid questions.

Comment: Just `print psycopg2` directly after importing it.

Comment: Given that the program runs in the same environment, you could do it in a shell as well. But if you're unsure, add a print somewhere before the line where it crashes (or as @ZiyadEdher pointed out, right after the import). I'm looking for what your `psycopg2` object is, actually. It should print out something along the lines of `<module 'psycopg2' from '/some/where/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py'>`, if all's well.

Comment: @IljaEverilä this is the output from print psycopg2.  <module 'psycopg2' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/psycopg2/__init_

Comment: Is the code you posted the entire code? Try to import the module in the interactive interpreter and trying calling `psycopg2.connect`.

Comment: @ZiyadEdher I tried to import the module in the interactive interpreter and calling psycopg2.connect but it is giving me the same error.

Comment: I'd almost go as far as to say that your installation is somehow corrupted. Please open up `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py` in your favourite editor and inspect if it looks ok (has the function `connect()` to begin with).

Comment: @IljaEverilä I have found a solution to my problem. I believe it was due to restricted user permissions on the /usr/local/lib folder. I ended up re-installing psycopg2 using a sudo install and and everything seems to be working fine now. This is my first StackOverflow question...how do I thank the contributors and close the question properly? Thanks a million for your patience :)

Comment: You could write up a self answer; it's perfectly ok to do so.